# Find the first missing positive integer

Tags: arrays

Given an array of integers, find the first missing positive integer in linear time and constant space. In other words, find the lowest positive integer that does not exist in the array. The array can contain duplicates and negative numbers as well.

For example, the input [3, 4, -1, 1] should give 2. The input [1, 2, 0] should give 3.

I did this but could not get through it and then searched it on google and got an answer on geeks for geeks but could not understand it. Can anyone provide a logic for this using simple concepts? I have just started competitive programming.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using capital letters and formatting your writings properly. Makes a great deal of a good impression to people.

Comment: @chevybow - Did you notice "*in linear time and constant space*"?

Comment: @PM77-1 no. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @DeiDei-From next question onwards,i will follow that.

Answer (score 1):

If a bitmap (extension of bitmask) is acceptable, then we could use 1 bit per positive integer and then just scroll the array. The bitmap is initialized with all bits to 0. As we scroll the array, we ignore negatives and turn the nth bit on when we encounter n. When we find, for example, 13, we turn the 13th bit into 1. (Likewise the number 1 would turn the first bit to 1) Then we scroll the bitmask and check the first zero. Done.

However, this might not be considered a constant complexity at all, since when the max positive int is MAXINT, we need the bitmap to be MAXINT bits large. Too bad. In theory, though, this is correct. Also O(2*N) = O(N)

So we have to store some information in the array or this is impossible to solve in O(N) in a single go.

Another solution consists in mapping array index with integer and storing information using sign. If the array size is L, for example, the missing int will be less or equal to L+1 (L+1 when the array if full like [1,2,3,4], unless this case counts as no element missing). **Thanks Jarod for the hint on this.**

Considered O(3N) is still O(N), how about:

step 1: scroll the array and swap negatives and zeroes moving them to the beginning. Turn everything non positive, that was swapped this way, to 1. The authentic positives will start at index j.

step 2: The whole array is now positive but true data lies from j to the end of the array. Scroll the subarray with authentic data and when you find, say, number H, turn index the Hth indexed number of the whole array negative. If H is greater than the array size, skip it. When you find for example 2, turn arr[1] (second element) negative.

step 3: scroll again the array checking for the first positive number. Basing on the index you know what the first missing positive integer is.

Comment: Right if they are above array size e.g 66 in [1,2,3,66], there is definitely a smaller int missing within [0,array size]

Comment: BTW, turning out of bound number into 1 should be step2, then each step would be `O(N)` instead of `N + (N - j)` for step 1 and `j` for step 2.

Comment: Total complexity will not change. Honestly I kinda preferred the bitmap... :)

Comment: Still, given your insight, about max value of the missing element, the bitmap can be compressed to (array size / 8) bytes which makes it much closer to constant

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the solution is to rearrange the array, and then finding the first 
number misplaced:

```
int find_missing(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {

        std::size_t e = i;

        while (0 < v[e]                      // Correct range
            && std::size_t(v[e]) <= v.size() // Correct range
            && std::size_t(v[e]) != e + 1    // Correct place
            && v[e] != v[v[e] - 1]           // Duplicate
        ) {
            std::swap(v[e], v[v[e] - 1]);
        }
    }
    // Now the array look like
    // {1, 2, 3, x, 5, 6, x}
    // Find first misplaced number
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if (std::size_t(v[i]) != i + 1) {
            return i + 1;   
        }
    }
    // All are correctly placed:
    return v.size();
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mpjJxt)

Comment: Idea was "sorting" in linear time as counting sort :-)

Comment: is this linear time? the sorting seem take n^2 time.

Comment: @RoundTwo: We have at most `n` swaps, each swap places `v[e]` at correct place `e+1` and there are only at most `n` correct places.